# Python script takes long to execute

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am not that much of an expert in python. My below script takes very long to execute during the split. Is there anything I need to change in the below code? My guess is that the slow behavior is due to the the "for-loop". Currently I am using python version 2.7.8

anybody please help on this

" soapUIResponseFolder" contains folder in the format of "Responses_20121115_TestSuite_1"

```
for subdir in glob.glob(soapUIResponseFolder):
                subdir = os.path.normpath(subdir)
                # This is a case when the os.walk returns a tuple (sequences). So we need to pick only the files path.
                onlyfiles = reduce(lambda x,y : x+y, [map(lambda x: root + "/" + x, files) for root, dirs, files in os.walk(subdir)])
                for file in onlyfiles:
                    i = 0
                    file = os.path.normpath(file) 
                    fileNameWithExt = os.path.basename(file)
                    filename, fileExtension = os.path.splitext(fileNameWithExt)
                    fileExtension = ".xml"
                    # The filename contains several parts with - as delimiter. So lets pick only the relevant ones
                    part1,part2,part3,part4,part5=filename.split("-")
                    filename = part2+"-"+part3 + fileExtension
                    responseFolder = os.path.split(os.path.dirname(file))[1]
                    inputFolder_new = inputFolder+"/"+responseFolder
                    outputFolder_new = outputFolder+"/"+responseFolder
```

Comment: What is meant by "during the split"?

Comment: during the split of folder

Comment: Your understanding of 'very long time' may be different from mine. Please be much more - completely - specific, i.e. how long does it take, how many folders are there, how many files in each folder? Also, what have you tried? Have you tried print a marker after the onlyfiles=... line so you can assess how long that takes?

Comment: approx. 100 folders and each folder contains 10 files with request and response xml which will need to split and moved to input and output folder

Comment: You missed out how long it takes to scan those files/folders... Be specific.

Answer (score 0):

**Folder scan speed**

Please strip down your python code to only find and print out relevant files and compare "speed" with `find somewhere -type f`. If your python code is notably slower, consider using `scandir` (3rd party) or Python 3.5 which includes it.

**Using glob**

`glob.glob(pattern)` accepts a shell-style pattern like `*.csv`, in your case you could have as easily used `os.listdir()`